# Different highslide onclick events based on screen size

Tags: onclick, highslide

I am upgrading our site so it is responsive.

At the moment a typical link of mine has a hard coded width for the onclick function:

An example of one I use is as follows:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { width: 700 } )">

<b>This is the title</b></a>

<div class="highslide-maincontent" style="font-weight:normal"> 

This is where the content is

</div>
```

However I would like it to have that for when the resolution is over 500px, under and I would want it to have a width of 90%

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width of the popup using CSS instead of using the width variable in the onclick. 
Define *width: 700px;* for all browser widths, and override this with *width: 90%;* when the browser has a max-width of 500px.

Use an onclick without the width variable:

```
onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this)"
```

Add this below the highslide.css file in the head section of your page:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
.highslide-html-content {
    width: 700px;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="(max-width: 500px)">
.highslide-html-content {
    width: 90%;
}
</style>
```